# flutter - how to trigger 'TextInput.show' effect without showing keyboard

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show text selection without keyboard.
It seems that triggering 'TextInput.show' always bring up keyboard.
But somehow without 'TextInput.show' I cannot select target text.
I wonder if there is alternative to select text without keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextFormFiled from flutter material package.

so first import material package to your class

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

then create TextFormFiled in Your Widget any where you want

```
TextFormField(),
```

then create controller in top of the build method.you can control text using controller later

```
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

then you can hide keybord popup automatically by

```
TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        ),
```

but it shows when you tap the TextFormFiled. so do you want to hide keyboard also tap state set as follows

```
TextFormField(
       onTap: (){
         FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
       },
        ),
```

Full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
       onTap: (){
         FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
       },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Happy Coding;

Comment: Thanks! But I am not using TextFormField, my code is more lower level